# Table calendar Flutter with Firestore data

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem when delimiting the start and end dates of the calendar from Firestore, I correctly retrieve the dates with the query in the collection and the calendar is delimited according to that but, when starting this screen it displays the month of the current date and in an instant it returns to the month of the initial date, the calendar waits for a tap to be built correctly, but obviously it stays in the month of startDate, the intention would be that it stays in the month of the current date.

[Calendar view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHpTd.gif)

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class Event {
  final String title;
  const Event(this.title);
  @override
  String toString() => title;
}

class CalendarMultiPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CalendarMultiPage({super.key});

  @override
  _CalendarMultiPageState createState() => _CalendarMultiPageState();
}

class _CalendarMultiPageState extends State<CalendarMultiPage> {
  final TextEditingController _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _detailsController = TextEditingController();
  final DateTime _selectedDay = DateTime.now();

  File? _image;

  late DateTime startDate = DateTime.now();
  late DateTime endDate = DateTime.now();
  Map<DateTime, List<Event>> events = {};

  late final ValueNotifier<List<Event>> _selectedEvents;
  final ValueNotifier<DateTime> _focusedDay = ValueNotifier(DateTime.now());
  final Set<DateTime> _selectedDays = LinkedHashSet<DateTime>(
    equals: isSameDay,
  );

  late PageController _pageController;
  CalendarFormat _calendarFormat = CalendarFormat.month;
  RangeSelectionMode _rangeSelectionMode = RangeSelectionMode.toggledOff;
  DateTime? _rangeStart;
  DateTime? _rangeEnd;

  List<Event> _eventsForSelectedDay = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadDatesProject();
    _selectedDays.add(_focusedDay.value);
    _selectedEvents = ValueNotifier(_getEventsForDay(_focusedDay.value));
    _focusedDay.value = DateTime.now();
  }

  void loadDatesProject() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String projectId = prefs.getString('projectId') ?? '';

    if (projectId.isNotEmpty) {
      DocumentSnapshot projectSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('companyProjects')
          .doc(projectId)
          .get();
      if (projectSnapshot.exists) {
        Map<String, dynamic> projectData =
            projectSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        final Timestamp startDateTimestamp =
            projectData['startDate'] as Timestamp;
        final Timestamp endDateTimestamp = projectData['endDate'] as Timestamp;

        setState(() {
          startDate = startDateTimestamp.toDate();
          endDate = endDateTimestamp.toDate();
        });

        final eventsQuery = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('task')
            .where('project', isEqualTo: projectId)
            .get();

        for (var eventDoc in eventsQuery.docs) {
          final eventData = eventDoc.data();
          final eventDate = eventData['date'].toDate();
          final event = Event(eventData['title']);

          if (events[eventDate] == null) {
            events[eventDate] = [event];
          } else {
            events[eventDate]!.add(event);
          }
          _selectedDays.add(eventDate);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Future getImage() async {
    final picker = ImagePicker();
    final pickedFile = await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return SimpleDialog(
          title: const Text('Seleccionar imagen desde:'),
          children: <Widget>[
            SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: () async {
                final pickedImage =
                    await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
                if (pickedImage != null) {
                  setState(() {
                    _image = File(pickedImage.path);
                  });
                }
                // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
                Navigator.pop(context, pickedImage);
              },
              child: const Text('Galería'),
            ),
            SimpleDialogOption(
              onPressed: () async {
                final pickedImage =
                    await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
                if (pickedImage != null) {
                  setState(() {
                    _image = File(pickedImage.path);
                  });
                }
                // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
                Navigator.pop(context, pickedImage);
              },
              child: const Text('Cámara'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );

    if (pickedFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusedDay.dispose();
    _selectedEvents.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  bool get canClearSelection =>
      _selectedDays.isNotEmpty || _rangeStart != null || _rangeEnd != null;

  List<Event> _getEventsForDay(DateTime day) {
    final selectedDate = DateTime(day.year, day.month, day.day);
    final List<Event> eventsForSelectedDay = [];

    events.forEach((eventDate, eventList) {
      final date = DateTime(
        eventDate.year,
        eventDate.month,
        eventDate.day,
      );

      if (date.isAtSameMomentAs(selectedDate)) {
        eventsForSelectedDay.addAll(eventList);
      }
    });

    return eventsForSelectedDay;
  }

  void _onDaySelected(DateTime selectedDay, DateTime focusedDay) {
    setState(() {
      if (_selectedDays.contains(selectedDay)) {
        _selectedDays.remove(selectedDay);
      } else {
        _selectedDays.clear(); // Deseleccionar otros días
        _selectedDays.add(selectedDay);
      }

      final formattedSelectedDay = DateTime(
        selectedDay.year,
        selectedDay.month,
        selectedDay.day,
      );

      _focusedDay.value = formattedSelectedDay;
      _rangeStart = null;
      _rangeEnd = null;
      _rangeSelectionMode = RangeSelectionMode.toggledOff;
      _eventsForSelectedDay = _getEventsForDay(selectedDay);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Cronograma de actividades'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ValueListenableBuilder<DateTime>(
            valueListenable: _focusedDay,
            builder: (context, value, _) {
              return _CalendarHeader(
                focusedDay: value,
                clearButtonVisible: canClearSelection,
                onTodayButtonTap: () {
                  setState(() => _focusedDay.value = DateTime.now());
                },
                onClearButtonTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _rangeStart = null;
                    _rangeEnd = null;
                    _selectedDays.clear();
                    _eventsForSelectedDay.clear();
                  });
                },
                onLeftArrowTap: () {
                  _pageController.previousPage(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    curve: Curves.easeOut,
                  );
                },
                onRightArrowTap: () {
                  _pageController.nextPage(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    curve: Curves.easeOut,
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
          TableCalendar<Event>(
            locale: 'es_ES',
            firstDay: startDate,
            lastDay: endDate,
            focusedDay: _focusedDay.value,
            headerVisible: false,
            selectedDayPredicate: (day) => _selectedDays.contains(day),
            rangeStartDay: _rangeStart,
            rangeEndDay: _rangeEnd,
            calendarFormat: _calendarFormat,
            rangeSelectionMode: _rangeSelectionMode,
            eventLoader: (day) {
              final selectedDate = DateTime(day.year, day.month, day.day);
              return events[selectedDate] ?? [];
            },
            onDaySelected: _onDaySelected,
            onCalendarCreated: (controller) => _pageController = controller,
            onPageChanged: (focusedDay) => _focusedDay.value = focusedDay,
            onFormatChanged: (format) {
              if (_calendarFormat != format) {
                setState(() => _calendarFormat = format);
              }
            },
            calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
              markerDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const Divider(), // Línea divisoria
          if (_eventsForSelectedDay.isNotEmpty)
            Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Eventos de ${DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(_focusedDay.value)}',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: _eventsForSelectedDay.map((event) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(event.title),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: _eventsForSelectedDay.isNotEmpty
          ? FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: _showAddActivityDialog,
              child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            )
          : null,
    );
  }

  void _showAddActivityDialog() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text(
            'Añadir actividad',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Fecha: ${_selectedDay!.day}-${_selectedDay!.month}-${_selectedDay!.year}',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 18,
                  ),
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: _titleController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Nombre',
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 8),
                TextField(
                  controller: _detailsController,
                  maxLines: null,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Detalles',
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 8),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: getImage,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 200,
                    width: 200,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    child: _image == null
                        ? const Icon(Icons.camera)
                        : Image.file(_image!),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text('Cancelar'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text('Añadir'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class _CalendarHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  final DateTime focusedDay;
  final VoidCallback onLeftArrowTap;
  final VoidCallback onRightArrowTap;
  final VoidCallback onTodayButtonTap;
  final VoidCallback onClearButtonTap;
  final bool clearButtonVisible;

  const _CalendarHeader({
    Key? key,
    required this.focusedDay,
    required this.onLeftArrowTap,
    required this.onRightArrowTap,
    required this.onTodayButtonTap,
    required this.onClearButtonTap,
    required this.clearButtonVisible,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final headerText = DateFormat.yMMM('es').format(focusedDay);

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(width: 16.0),
          SizedBox(
            width: 130.0,
            child: Text(
              headerText,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 26.0),
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.calendar_today, size: 20.0),
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
            onPressed: onTodayButtonTap,
          ),
          if (clearButtonVisible)
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.clear, size: 20.0),
              visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
              onPressed: onClearButtonTap,
            ),
          const Spacer(),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.chevron_left),
            onPressed: onLeftArrowTap,
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
            onPressed: onRightArrowTap,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The code is taken from the table calendar examples in the flutter library on github, I have only changed some aspects to delimit the dates with the firestore data.
I have tried changing the variable startDate by DateTime.now() and with that it does not happen this problem of returning to the month of startDate, but the idea is to have opening to all the range of dates of startDate and endDate.